# AWS SQS Reprocessing Inflight Messages

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sqs

I have a file reader which drops each row of a CSV into an SQS; a .Net lambda function is subscribed to receive each row and process it individually.

When an item has finished processing (around 1-3 seconds) it is deleted from the Queue.

Once a row is processed it sends a packet of data to another area of the system, but what I'm seeing in the logs is that we are receiving duplicate packets of data from the function.

Due to the lambda function running concurrently; my working theory is that the queue items are still in flight when a function becomes available to consume another item - and so it consumes an item which is already being processed.

As the delete operation happens last my solution is to move the delete operation to the start of the function.

However I am worried about whether this is sensible, as if the function hangs or times out while processing we're going to have lost the packet entirely. Also if I delete the item from the queue; will the function be able to continue once it's parsed the data from the message?

So my question is in 2 parts

1. Is it possible for a lambda function subscribed to an SQS to
   receive an in flight message while another instance of that same
   function is already processing it?
2. Are there any potential issues
   with me deleting the queue item as soon as the function has picked
   it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid such solution. Your function may throw exception or can be killed because of 5min limit to lambdas and you will lost your message

Instead i would try to adjust visibility timeout, according to what time is needed by your function to process the message (or messages). 
On the other hand you can decrease number of messages that your listener read every time (10 by default). 
So it will decrease overal time to process and time to process will be smaller than visibilityTimeout (or timeout by default)
If you can't predict how much time you need to process message, you can adjust (extend) visibilityTimeout AFTER you received the message.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the visibility timeout, it's something i hadn't considered. Marked as Answer :)